# Trigger static method on react testing library

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to cover the test case for the static method. Please help!!

[image]

PFB my test code

[image]

Comment: Add everything indispensable to give useful answer to the question. Paste in text, maybe as a block quote or code block instead of using images of text rendered.

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)